# How to use different local.setttings.json files in Azure function app

Tags: azure-functions, config

I am trying to create a toggle in my Azure function app, in which you are able to switch between using different local.settings.json files. My current setup includes adding a new profile in the launchSettings.json file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "TestProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "host start --port 7072 --pause-on-error"
    },
    "TestProjectQA": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "host start --port 7072 --pause-on-error",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "QA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Selecting which project at runtime will determine which settings.json file is used. If TestProject is selected, the local.settings.json file should be executed and if TestProjectQA is selected, the quarterly.settings.json file should be executed.

However, I am unsure how to execute the quarterly.settings.json file when the TestProjectQA is selected.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe there is no way to configure which local settings file is picked up, if you are using C#, you can customize the configuration source using dependency injection as shown in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources).

Referencing the docs, you would need to create a startup file like so

```cs
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }
    }
}
```

and also update the `.csproj` file with the following to ensure the customer configuration file is copied over when built

```xml
<None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>      
</None>
<None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```